# How to install GLIBC_2.14 without admin right

Tags: glibc

I want to use gdc-client, however, after I download it and run it. the system reported as:

```
./gdc-client: /lib64/libc.so.6: version `GLIBC_2.14' not found (required by /tmp/_MEI5oSpPi/libz.so.1)
```

It is our University Server, I don't have any admin right. Do you know how to install GLIBC_2.14 without admin right?

```
[shg047@tscc-login2 software]$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :base-4.0-amd64:base-4.0-noarch:core-4.0-amd64:core-4.0-noarch:graphics-4.0-amd64:graphics-4.0-noarch:printing-4.0-amd64:printing-4.0-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS release 6.6 (Final)
Release:        6.6
Codename:       Final
[
```

Comment: Build glibc-2.14 in your /home/name/, install the lib´s to /home/[name]/lib/ ... and start the app with : `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/[name]/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH && ./gdc-client`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Multiple glibc libraries on a single host](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/847179/multiple-glibc-libraries-on-a-single-host)

Comment: @KnudLarsen Your solution will not work for reasons explained here: ​http://stackoverflow.com/a/851229/50617

Comment: Did you find a solution ? I've the same issue.

Answer (score 3):

gdc-client [github](https://github.com/NCI-GDC/gdc-client/issues/84) issued this problem that **glibc 2.12 is the latest that's available for CentOS 6**.

If your system is CentOS release 6.6, I think you should download the [gdc-client source code](https://github.com/NCI-GDC/gdc-client) and compile it yourself. gdc-client is based on the py2.

1. `git clone https://github.com/NCI-GDC/gdc-client`
2. `python setup.py install`

You may meet the problem

> The 'lxml==3.5.0b1' distribution was not found and is required by gdc-client

or

> ImportError: /usr/lib64/libxml2.so.2: version `LIBXML2_2.9.0' not found (required by lxml/etree.so)

You need to install `libxslt` and `libxml2` in your home path. And add `xml2-config` and `xslt-config` to your path. `export PATH="/prog_path/libxslt-1.1.29/bin:/prog_path/libxml2-2.9.4/bin:$PATH"`

Then

3. `pip uninstall lxml`
4. `pip install lxml==3.5.0b1 --install-option="--auto-rpath"`

Finnaly, compile gdc-client source code.

5. `python setup.py install`

**It worked.**